# If statement not working? Player wins function Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

```
    var boxId = ['boxMid','boxLeft','boxRight','boxTopMid','boxTopRight','boxTopLeft','boxLow        Mid','boxLowLeft','boxLowRight'];

    var turn = 0;

    var pOne = "X";
    var pTwo = "O";
    var blankBox = "";

    var boxMid = document.getElementById('boxMid').innerhtml;
    var boxLeft = document.getElementById('boxLeft').innerhtml;
    var boxRight = document.getElementById('boxRight').innerhtml;
    var boxTopMid = document.getElementById('boxTopMid').innerhtml;
    var boxTopLeft = document.getElementById('boxTopLeft').innerhtml;
    var boxTopRight = document.getElementById('boxTopRight').innerhtml;
    var boxLowMid = document.getElementById('boxLowMid').innerhtml;
    var boxLowLeft = document.getElementById('boxLowLeft').innerhtml;
    var boxLowRight = document.getElementById('boxLowRight').innerhtml;

    var i = 0;
```

My player win function is not working and I've had several others look at it, so I figured I would get an outside perspective.

```
    function xWins() {
        if(boxId[0,1,2] == 'X'|| 
        boxTopLeft == "X" && boxTopMid == "X" && boxTopRight == "X"||
        boxLowMid == "X" && boxLowLeft == "X" && boxLowRight == "X"||
        boxMid == "X" && boxTopMid == "X" && boxLowMid == "X"||
        boxLeft == "X" && boxTopLeft == "X" && boxLowLeft == "X"||
        boxRight == "X" && boxTopRight == "X" && boxLowRight == "X"||
        boxMid == "X" && boxTopLeft == "X" && boxLowRight == "X"||
        boxMid == "X" && boxLowLeft == "X" && boxTopRight == "X" ) {
        alert ('Player One Wins!');
        turn = 1;
        }
    }
    function oWins(){
        if(boxId[0,1,2] == "O"|| 
        boxTopLeft == "O" && boxTopMid == "O" && boxTopRight == "O"||
        boxLowMid == "O" && boxLowLeft == "O" && boxLowRight == "O"||
        boxMid == "O" && boxTopMid == "O" && boxLowMid == "O"||
        boxLeft == "O" && boxTopLeft == "O" && boxLowLeft == "O"||
        boxRight == "O" && boxTopRight == "O" && boxLowRight == "O"||
        boxMid == "O" && boxTopLeft == "O" && boxLowRight == "O"||
        boxMid == "O" && boxLowLeft == "O" && boxTopRight == "O" ) {
        alert ('Player Two Wins!');
        turn = 0;
        }
    }

    function test(bx){
    if(document.getElementById(boxId[bx]).innerHTML == ""){
            if (turn<1) {
                document.getElementById(boxId[bx]).innerHTML = pOne;
                document.onclick (turn++);
                oWins();
                xWins();
            }   

            if (turn == 1) {
                document.getElementById(boxId[bx]).innerHTML = pTwo;
                document.onclick (turn--);
                oWins();
                xWins();
            }
        }
    }

    function reset() {
        for(i=0;i<boxId.length;i++)
        document.getElementsByClassName('boxy')[i].innerHTML = blankBox;
    }
```

As far as I know, everything else works except for my scoreboard, but I'll figure that out when I get there. Please keep in mind that I am a high school student that has less than 2 months of real experience coding, so I probably did some things that could've been a lot easier, and more DRY.

Comment: I tried calling the array I had set up and that didn't work either, that's why the first part of my if statements is different from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of Bug: You are telling it that oWins() by calling the oWins function, where it runs through your cascasde of OR conditionals to which one of them is matching. So you have 2 problems. 1, that oWins() is always testing true via your OR statements, and 2, that xWins() is being called after the oWins() function that is evaluating to true each time. Stringing together OR conditionals like that is problematic and often difficult to debug.

```
  if (turn == 1) {
            document.getElementById(boxId[bx]).innerHTML = pTwo;
            document.onclick (turn--);
            oWins();
            xWins();
        }
```